# Jquery array appendTo through function

Tags: jquery, arrays, appendto

Trying to append array values to divs, this part works , nothing wrong here, but i need the array values to be formatted and it would be simple and neat to just pass the value through a function right before the appendTo() jquery function, dont know if this is possible though...

have a long list of this: `$(c[3]).appendTo('#output_div_id1');`

what im trying to achieve is `$( number_format(c[3])).appendTo('#div');`

This does not seem to be working. Ideas how i could achieve this?

Comment: It depends on what `number_format` returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or just use append().
http://api.jquery.com/append/

Example:

```
<div id="element">Hello</div>
$('#element').append(function(index, html) {
    return ' world!';
});
```

Comment: this won't work - it appends the result of the function to every element matching the given selector, and *not* the contents of his array.

Comment: Thats kind of what i wanted :) dont have to change the array just output the correct numbers, why didnt i think of this? :) thanks buddy

Comment: @idontgetdottynetty that's not my point - there's nothing in this answer that handles adding your original array to `#element` one element at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the entries before you append them

OR

You can try modifying the jQuery prototype:

```
$.fn.numberFormat = function () {
    var htmlStr = $(this).html();

    //do stuff to the html (or whatever you're changing)

    return $(this).html(htmlStr);
};
```

and then use it like:

```
$(c[3]).numberFormat().appendTo('#div");
```

Comment: Yeah i tried formatting them through a for loop     for(var i = 3; i < c.length; i++)
    {
     
      c[i] = number_format(c[i],0, ',', ',');
     
     
    }   but for some reason that didnt work..

Answer (score 0):

Given an array `a`, and a transmutation function `f`, the code below will append each element of the array to the given selector having passed it through that function:

```
$.fn.append.apply($('#div'), $.map(a, f));
```

so, in your case given:

```
function number_format(n) {
    return n.toFixed(2);  // modify to suit
}
```

you would use:

```
$.fn.append.apply($('#div'), $.map(c, number_format));
```

and the result will be that every element of `c` will be passed to `number_format` and *then* appended to the div, leaving the original array untouched.